# Maven Resource Filtering with Profile Properties

Tags: maven, maven-profiles, maven-resources-plugin

I have the following pom.xml:

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>resource-fail</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <foo.bar>BazBat</foo.bar>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Development</id>
            <!--
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            -->
            <properties>
                <foo.bar>Development</foo.bar>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Notice that the `activation` element on the `profile` is commented out

I also have the following in `src/main/java/application.properties`

```
myproperty=${foo.bar}
```

So what I expect Maven to do is simply replace `${foo.bar}` with `BazBat`, unless the Development profile is activiated, then I expect Maven to replace `${foo.bar}` with `Development`

When I run `mvn package` it sets the value to `BazBat`.  Good, the resource filtering is working as expected.

However when I run `mvn package -P Development` it sets the value to `BazBat`

To confuse things further, if uncomment the `activation` element on the profile and run `mvn package` it will set `${foo.bar}` to `Development`

I've even run `mvn help:active-profiles package` to have it output the active profile name and under both scenarios above it says that the Development profile is active, but filtering still does not work without the `activeByDefault` flag being set.

To sum up:

- Maven properly overrides properties with values from the profile if the profile is `activeByDefault`
- Maven does **not** override the property if I activate the profile via the command line switch

What is going on?

My environment:

```
> mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T11:29:23-06:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.8.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

**Update:**  I've upgraded to the latest maven (3.3.3) - the problem persists.  My new environment:

```
> mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T06:57:37-05:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Comment: Did you get it working? Even I'm facing same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186963/value-from-maven-profile-properties-is-not-getting-used-in-properties-file, please review

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while running this with m2e in Eclipse. Solved it by enabling the profile in the plugin :
Right-click your project in Eclipse, then select Maven -> Select Maven Profiles...
Here you can enable the development profile

After I did this, maven filtered my resources using the property values set in the profile. I removed the "-P" argument in my Run Configuration, as this was no longer needed.

This might also work if you define and enable the profile in your settings.xml file, but I didn't try that.

Answer (score -3):

You need to remove the space between -P and development when you execute:
mvn package -PDevelopment